# using hybridauth behind a load balancer

Tags: php, laravel, load-balancing, hybridauth

I have a few running servers, behind a load balancer

I'm using hybridauth to authenticate users throw google and facebook

By reviewing the hybridauth code it seems that it uses the session to store data while it pinging back and forward with the given provider.

When i'm behind a load balancer i'm expose to a scenario: that the machine that started the authentication process is not the machine that will end the authentication process and the session data will vary.. so the authentication will fail

what can i do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could easily store sessions in redis or memcache with laravel and that would solve your problem.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate a little. Show an example or link to a tutorial?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, saving the session data in redis, would be a valid solution, but that means that i will have to add the functionality, i was hoping that hybridauth has a build in solution.

Comment: I couldn't find any tutorial or example that dose that. but the main issue here is that i need a way to preserve, the session data between the requests. I's seems weird that i do not find anyone complain about it, so my guess is that i'm missing something

Comment: https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis The PHP Redis Extension allows for configuring PHP Sessions to be stored on a redis server.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone having an issue like this either with hybridauth or any other thing that stores session Data replication is the answer. I fixed similar issues setting up replicated network storage with GlusterFS.